# Query Apache Solr for metadata

Tags: solr

I was wondering if it was possible to query Solr for some index-metadata, e.g. the most frequent words in the index?

If so, how do you do this? Unfortunately I wasn't able to find anything about this.

thx for any help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [LukeRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler)